# Book about an industrialist that finds an animal in space that creates portals

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, space, hard-sci-fi

I am looking for a sci-fi book I read in the late 80's or early 90's dealing with a a rich space industrialist that finds an animal in space that, when stimulated, creates propulsion. Later in the book he finds he can make portals and he ends up going into the future.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: I removed the decade tags to make room for the [time-travel] tag. It's not definite that they were applicable, since it's when you read the book, not when they were published.

Comment: Timemaster it is. Thank you so much. I have been trying to figure this book out for years. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the 1992 novel [*Timemaster*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?51657) by [Robert L. Forward](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?815), who is more famous as the author of [*Dragon's Egg*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon%27s_Egg). Here's a description from an [Amazon customer review](http://www.amazon.com/Timemaster-Robert-L-Forward/product-reviews/0812516443/ref=dp_db_cm_cr_acr_txt?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1) by David Bonesteel:

> Space entrepeneur Randy Hunter discovers a kind of space-dwelling plant composed of negative matter, which allows him to develop interstellar spaceflight and time travel, not to mention acheiving all of his dreams, winning the girl, foiling his drug-addicted rival, and becoming an all-around great guy.

There is a quotation from *Timemaster* [here](http://lichen.phys.uregina.ca/eclectic/timemaster.html).